# Get data from database.

Tags: iphone, mysql, database, ios, uitableview

Ok,  I am able to connect to the mysql database from my iPhone app, I have set it up in a tableview.  So when I call the didSelectRow method it stores the users Id number, not the indexRow number. My question is how can I use that stored id to retrieve the rest of the information, so when the row is pressed it brings up the rest of that users particular Information. I know I am not showing any code here that is because I'm writing this from my iPad, so I hope you cam follow what im trying to do and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can help u in one way that u have to store the array coming from the data base in an array in appdel u can call that array at any time where we want sample code is here

this is the array in appdb

```
NSMutableArray *fruit_details;
```

call one method in Appdb

```
[self readStudentFromDatabase];
```

then write the code here in that method

```
NSArray *documentpaths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDir = [documentpaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
fruit_details=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//open the database from the users filesystem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement ="select * from stu";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement,-1, &compiledStatement , NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            NSString *aName =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)];
            NSString *amarks=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,1)];
            NSString *arank =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,2)];
            NSString *aaddr =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,3)];
            NSString *aemail =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,4)];
            NSString *aphno =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,5)];
            NSString *aage =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,6)];
            NSString *asex =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,7)];
            NSString *adate =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,8)];
            NSString *aimage=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 9)];
            // // Create a new animal object with the data from the database

        //animal *animal_object=[[animal alloc]initWithName:aName description:arollNO url:amarks];

            //add the animal object to the animal ar
            //[animals addObject:animal_object];
            temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [temp addObject:aName];
            [temp addObject:amarks];
            [temp addObject:arank];
            [temp addObject:aaddr];
            [temp addObject:aemail];
            [temp addObject:aphno];
            [temp addObject:aage];
            [temp addObject:asex];
            [temp addObject:adate];
            [temp addObject:aimage];
            [fruit_details addObject:temp];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

I think  this may help u.....

Answer (score 0):

Is **stored id** what you get from the db? My understanding is that when user select a row, you want to go to a new view and fetch the corresponding information from the db using that **stored id**.

Comment: Yes that is exactly correct. The id is what I get from the db, I  just cannot or don't understand how to fetch the corresponding data and put it into a new view?